# Update element in nested array, immutably

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update the price of a BMW 730d in the following json.

The cars object should be a new object, (Immutability), so I need to use the map function.

And I don't want to use libraries like immutable or normalizr. The aim is to get my head around the map function, but I'm stuck evaluating the brand name.

```
const cars =
[
    {
        brand: 'BMW',
        model: [
            {
                name: '535d',
                price: 35000
            }, {
                name: '730d',
                price: 55000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        brand: 'Mercedes',
        model: [
            {
                name: 'roadstar',
                price: 75000
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

This is what I have so far :

```
// trying to update the price of a BMW 730d

const newCars= cars.map(brand => {
    console.log(brand);
    // and now ?

});
```

But now I'm stuck.

Who helps me out?

Thanks!

[EDIT] I added an id "brand" in the json to identify the models.

Comment: Ugly structure using unique keys in each object. Do you control the structure generated?

Comment: brand is always an object literal, once having BMW as a key. map doesn’t make your data immutable.

Comment: no ^. brand, in this code, is the whole object, in which the unique key of each object resides.

Comment: Use `if(brand.BMW)` instead

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn That works, But I still need to create a new cars object..

Comment: @OleEHDufour if that is the whole issue what is the `if(brand=='BMW')` all about? And do you or don't you control the structure? Is not developer friendly at all

Comment: @charlietfl That's just part of my code. I see it should be brand.BMW but how to create the new cars object ?

Comment: Do a search for immutable objects. Will end up in MDN docs but probably lots of tutorials also

Comment: Would be so much cleaner and easier to work with structuring it `[{brand:'BMW', models:[...]}, {brand:'Mercedes', models:[...]}`

Comment: @charlietfl You're right. I changed it. But how to proceed?

Comment: I updated the json

Comment: Did you do any research into how to create immutable objects? I don't understand why you say you want immutable but also say you want to update a price. Seems conflicting

Comment: Once you figure out your new Car() to return the immutable object you want would just be `let newArr = cars.map(car=>new Car(car))`

Comment: If you’re updating your question then please put the edited structure below the original and mark it with ‘EDIT:’. I gave you the answer for your question I even replied to your comments. You are rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would check whether the current object concerns the BMWs and return a new object (with the desired new model list) for it, or just return the unchanged object otherwise:

```
const newCars = cars.map(car => {
    if (car.brand == "BMW") {
        return {
            brand: "BMW",
            model: car.model.map(model => {
                // …
            }),
        };
    } else {
        return car;
    }
});
```

For updating the respective object in the `model` array, use exactly the same approach again.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I couldn't get my head around it. Thank you  Bergi! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

As a technicality, your phrasing of immutability is incorrect. Immutable means a fundamental inability to mutate. In your case, you're simply making the decision to not mutate.

Unfortunately, based on the structure of your data, you have to get a little messy to extract the key. `Object.keys` is the best way I can think of. It returns an array, so you have to key in to the index `0`.

```
cars.map(car => {
  const brand = Object.keys(car)[0];
  if (brand === 'BMW') {
  }
})
```

Comment: I just want to say that I wish to create a new cars object...(I'm using react)

Answer (score -1):

You have to test on the object's property, you can use the method "hasOwnProperty" of an object to know if an object x has a property y or not, in your case you have To do the following test:

```
If(brand.hasOwnProperty('BMW')) {
  // To do 
}
```

Comment: I think this is both a misunderstanding of what hasOwnProperty does, as well as not an answer to the question.